# How to pronounce IPA "/rɑːp/"? (Old English)

Tags: pronunciation, old-english, ipa

I'm making a video which includes some information about the ancient Saxon and Norman political organization of the English county of Sussex. One thing I am stuck on is the Old English pronunciation of "Rape", which is the old term for the six political / administrative areas of Sussex. There are six rapes (see [Rape (county subdivision)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rape_(county_subdivision))) in Sussex. This has nothing to do with violence, as the etymology of the word is given as having descended from the Old English word for "rope". Let's not argue about that; it seems that this has been more or less settled in linguistics at this point.

It is written "...the derivation of the word from the Old English rāp (rope) has been made practically certain."  The text links "rāp" to Wiktionary and this gives the IPA pronunciation as [/rɑːp/](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/rap#Old_English).

My problem is how is /rɑːp/ supposed to be pronounced? In the IPA pronunciation guides I've looked at online there is no character *ɑː* listed! Perhaps the ː isn't part of the vowel coding and means something unrelated to the vowel? I don't see this anywhere indicated, perhaps because I don't know where to look.

I'd love an explanation! I'd particularly like to know how to pronounce /rɑːp/.  If the OE were supposed to be pronounced the same as the word for sexual violence, the IPA would look like /ɹeɪp/, so THAT'S out, at least.

ETA: Since there seems to be some question on this point, I am NOT asking how the word "rape" is pronounced in connection with the term for the Sussex administrative district. The contemporary pronunciation is the same as the word pertaining to "sexual assault".  I am asking how the given IPA code is pronounced.  It's irrelevant that this is how it was pronounced in OLD English.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112774/discussion-on-question-by-cyberherbalist-how-to-pronounce-ipa-rp-old-eng).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Old English had short and long vowels, which were pronounced more or less the same, except the long vowels were longer (in time). In IPA, the /ː/ is a long symbol, which means that the vowel before it is long; so /ɑː/ means the long version of the vowel, while /ɑ/ would mean a shorter version.

For example, [hæt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/h%C3%A6t#Old_English), pronounced /xæt/, in Old English had a short vowel, which turned into our modern English *hat*, with a "short a", and [wæt](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/w%C3%A6t), pronounced /wæːt/ and meaning *wet*, had a long vowel. The terms "short vowel" (for the vowel in *hat*) and "long vowel" (for the vowel in *hate*) derive from the fact that in Early Middle English, these actually were the short and long versions of the same vowel; the vowels have changed since then.

Comment: That's super-informative, thanks!

Comment: @Cyberherbalist in other words, it's not part of the vowel coding, but it means something that is related to the vowel.

Comment: There's a whole Wikipedia article on [Phonological history of Old English](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phonological_history_of_Old_English) (might be helpful).

Answer (score 3):

It is pronounced as a long a: /ɑː/ and appears in British English in p**ar**k, h**ar**k, and c**ar**p. In some forms of American English, the 'r' may be lightly pronounced where it would not be in /rɑːp/.

To hear "carp" spoken in various varieties of English: https://www.wordreference.com/definition/carp

Comment: The full OED says this particular sense of ***rape*** (the six administrative districts into which Sussex was formerly divided) is pronounced **/reɪp/**, same as the 11 other entries for this word.

Comment: As indicated above, the question is not how to pronounce "rape" in connection with the Sussex administrative district (and you're right, current pronunciation is as it shows in the OED). The question is how to pronounce it according to the IPA symbols shown.

Comment: Are you sure that OE /ɑː/ had the same sound as modern UK/RP /ɑː/?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., I think you've got that a little backwards. The IPA represents the sound itself, irrespective of pronunciation drift. If the word in question drifts to a different pronunciation, what changes is the IPA. The IPA for the original pronunciation remains the same, just as the original pronunciation remains the same in the past.

Comment: @Cyberherbalist No, that's a common misunderstanding, which is why I brought it up. When used in square brackets IPA symbols represent actual phonetic sounds. However, when used in slanty brackets, to give a language particular phonemic transcription, the symbols used do ***not*** necessarily represent a sound that is the sme as would be represented by that symbol in the intertnational IPA system. So, for example, the STRUT vowel is normally represented by an upsidedown hat symbol in 'IPA' phonemic transcriptions of English. ... (cont)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist ... But the typical sound for the STRUT vowel in English is nothing like [ʌ], but is actually almost exactly [ɐ]. Similarly, modern AmE or RP speakers do not have any [r] for /r/, which is a actually a trill, in either AmE or BrE. We have a [ɹ]. Language specific transcription conventions do not strictly adhere to the InternationalPA system. And in fact they usually can't - the symbols for cardinal vowels are idealised points on a scalar system. There is no symbol ... (cont)

Comment: @Cyberherbalist ... for the sound we associate with any English /i/, the FLEECE vowel. The reason is that they are all more open than IPA [i] and more closed than IPA [e]. So we just use /i/ because it's the nearest symbol, and it's one that fits neatly with the orthographhic conventions of the English writing system. [Professor John Wells gives some useful insights and discussion of this here](https://www.phon.ucl.ac.uk/home/wells/ipa-english.htm).

Comment: We pronounce the /r/ in *carp* "lightly"? I don't even know what that means; the /r/ is an essential feature of the word *carp*; without it, the word would be *cop*.

Comment: @Peter Shor It means that an "r" may (or may not) be heard depending on the speaker. Without an "r" caap" - not 'cop'. Have a listen on the WRF site I linked to.

Comment: @Greybeard: I was talking about General American English, where *carp* without an "r" indeed is *cop*. (Although maybe not in all the r-less varieties of American English, which are Boston, New York, and several Southern dialects).

Comment: @PeterShor I understand that having a distinction between /ɔ/, /ɑ/, and /ɒ/ (i.e. not having the cot-caught merger or the father-bother merger) is rare in American English, and my dialect (a Southern one) is one of the few that retains that distinction, so it seems likely to me that the non-rhotic Southern dialects may also have that distinction. The *carp* and *cop* vowels are certainly different, even with the r removed, in my dialect.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore., that was a very useful series of comments you provided! It makes perfect sense. I also thank you for the link to the John Wells quote! It's been a long time, but I remember I used to own an English/Esperanto dictionary written by him. A "Teach Yourself" book if I remember correctly.

Answer (score 3):

The sign that looks like a colon in your question should be two small triangles one above the other. It indicates a long vowel. You can see the character here [Triangular colon](https://teflpedia.com/Triangular_colon)

Listen to the pronunciation of non-rhotic *apart* in the following video. This will indicate how to pronounce /a:/ - Note that the speaker is Australian but this doesn't affect that particular vowel much.

[Vowel Sounds In English With IPA - The Ultimate Video To Improve Your Pronunciation Of Vowels](https://youtu.be/JmXLAeVJDU0?t=236)

It's probably worth reading the rest of the article but here's an excerpt:

> English Vowel IPA Examples – Long Single Vowels
>
> Vowel Phonetic Symbol   &    IPA Examples in Words
>
> /i:/     week /wi:k/, feet /fi:t/, media /ˈmiː.di.jə/
> **/ɑ:/    hard /ha:/, park /pa:k/, article /ɑː.tɪ.kəl/** /ɔ:/    fork /fɔ:k/, walk /wɔ:k/, August /ɔːˈɡʌst/ /ɜ:/   heard /hɜ:d/, word
> /wɜ:d/, surface /ˈsɜː.fɪs/ /u:/   boot /bu:t/, group /gru:p/,
> beautiful /ˈbjuː.tɪ.fəl/
>
> What are English Long Vowels in the IPA? There are 5 IPA symbols for
> English long vowels. The IPA for English long vowels are: /i:/, /ɑ:/,
> /ɔ:/, /ɜ:/, /u:/.
>
> [IPA ENGLISH VOWEL SOUNDS & EXAMPLES](https://www.speechactive.com/english-vowels-ipa-international-phonetic-alphabet/#:%7E:text=What%20are%20English%20Long%20Vowels%20in%20the%20IPA%3F,practise%20each%20of%20the%20long%20English%20vowels%20phonetics.)

**Conclusion**

If you are English then you will be used to not pronouncing the "r" in "harp" so in that case , /rɑːp/ would rhyme with "harp".

If on the other hand you are from a country where the "r" in "harp" *is* pronounced, this may not be so useful.

However /rɑːp/ is Old English so the initial "r" *would* be pronounced quite strongly.

I hope this helps somewhat. Please feel free to ask further questions.